How can I split a column containing several key:value pairs?
I have a dataset containing data for some vehicles. In this dataset, the last column corresponds to the routing information of each vehicle (the header is 'route').
The data in this column has a format as follows:
[{
    "longitude": 101, 
    "latitude": 3, 
    "timestamp": 2, 
    "accuracy": 0.5, 
    "hdop": 1
}] 

Each of these set of data represent a coordinate. Also note that not all coordinates have the "hdop" and "accuracy" keys.
I want to split the data in this last column based on the "longitude", "latitude", "timestamp", "accuracy", "hdop".
Any suggestions on how I can do that please? I'm really new to Python so I am struggling to move forward.
I have tried the following commands:
import csv
import json
import ast
import pandas as pd

# Read data into a Pandas data frame
df = pd.read_csv('Trips Jan Week 1.csv')
df['route'] = pd.Series(df['route'],dtype="string")

# Extract the last column as a string
routes = df.iloc[:, -1].astype(str)

# Remove any leading or trailing characters before parsing the JSO
routes2 = routes.apply(lambda x: x.strip('[]').strip())
print(routes2)
print(type(routes2))

The results are as follows:
0       {"longitude":101.70393638087968,"latitude":3.1...
1       {"longitude":101.5249183,"latitude":3.0761391,...
2       {"longitude":101.70862944829587,"latitude":3.1...
3       {"longitude":101.705162,"latitude":3.1590512,...
4       {"longitude":101.71380749913092,"latitude":3.1...
                          ...                        
7928    {"longitude":101.7115741,"latitude":3.1961516,...
7929    {"longitude":101.71194960096184,"latitude":3.1... 
7930    {"longitude":101.71191491852223,"latitude":3.1...
7931    {"longitude":101.6748983,"latitude":3.1257983,...
7932    {"longitude":101.69488815920366,"latitude":3.0...
Name: route, Length: 7933, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

The results I would like to get for each of these would therefore be in a table as follows:



Longitude
Latitude
Timestamp
Accuracy
Hdop




101
3
2
0.5
1




BTW it would be good if you could provide a [example] to work with, not a vague data description or truncated output.

I can see 2 ways to accomplish this: either apply pandas.Series to the only list item in the column of interest, or explicitly assign values to new columns, reaching them by index and key pair:
import pandas as pd

# Preparing test data
route = [
    [{'longitude': 101, 'latitude': 3, 'timestamp': 2, 'accuracy': 0.5, 'hdop': 1}],
    [{'longitude': 102, 'latitude': 4, 'timestamp': 3, 'accuracy': 0.7, 'hdop': 2}],
    [{'longitude': 103, 'latitude': 5, 'timestamp': 4,                  'hdop': 3}],
    [{'longitude': 104, 'latitude': 6, 'timestamp': 5, 'accuracy': 0.1           }]
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'route': route})


# Option 1: Extract the route data by applying pandas.Series
route = df['route'].str[0].apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df, route], axis='columns')


# Option 2: Assign values by dictionary key
df = df.assign(
    longitude = df['route'].str[0].str['longitude']
    , latitude = df['route'].str[0].str['latitude']
    , timestamp = df['route'].str[0].str['timestamp']
    , accuracy = df['route'].str[0].str['accuracy']
    , hdop = df['route'].str[0].str['hdop']
)

In the second case, you can set/change the order of columns if needed, and the columns will be created even if there are no items with the specified keys. But you need to know all their names in advance. The first case is useful when the set of possible keys is unknown.
If lists can have multiple dictionaries, we first explode a column and then apply pandas.Series to it. For example:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from ast import literal_eval

csv_data = '''mark,route
A,"[{'longitude': 101, 'latitude': 3, 'timestamp': 2, 'accuracy': 0.5, 'hdop': 1},{'longitude': 102, 'latitude': 4, 'timestamp': 3, 'accuracy': 0.7, 'hdop': 2}]"
B,"[{'longitude': 103, 'latitude': 5, 'timestamp': 4, 'hdop': 3},{'longitude': 104, 'latitude': 6, 'timestamp': 5, 'accuracy': 0.1}]"
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), converters={'route': literal_eval})

df = df.explode('route', ignore_index=True)
route = df['route'].apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df, route], axis=1)

print(df.drop(columns='route'))

  mark  longitude  latitude  timestamp  accuracy  hdop
0    A      101.0       3.0        2.0       0.5   1.0
1    A      102.0       4.0        3.0       0.7   2.0
2    B      103.0       5.0        4.0       NaN   3.0
3    B      104.0       6.0        5.0       0.1   NaN

